# XQuery to retrieve value

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I have this XML that I am trying to retrieve a value from...

```
<ExportPartyAddressingResponse xmlns="http://www.ediel.no/Export">
  <CompanyListMessage>
    <Header GeneratedAt="2021-11-11T05:00:02Z" SenderApplication="www.ediel.se" />
    <Market Code="EL" CountryCode="SE">
      <Company>
        <Name>7H Kraft EnergifÃ¶rmedling AB</Name>
        <ContactInformation>
          <Item Type="Telephone">+46321532323</Item>
          <Item Type="Telefax">+46321532321</Item>
          <Item Type="Web">www.7hkraft.se</Item>
        </ContactInformation>
        <Identifiers>
          <Key Type="EdielId">60900</Key>
          <Key Type="OrgNo">556525-8075</Key>
          <Key Type="SvKId">7HK</Key>
        </Identifiers>
        <Addresses>
          <Address Type="Postal">
            <Address1>Box 25</Address1>
            <PostCode>22100</PostCode>
            <Place>LUND</Place>
            <CountryCode>SE</CountryCode>
          </Address>
        </Addresses>
        <Roles>
          <Role>PowerSupplier</Role>
        </Roles>
        <EdielAddressing>
          <EDIFACTAddressing>
            <EDIFACTDetails Type="PRODAT">
              <EDICharset>UNOC</EDICharset>
              <EDISyntax>3</EDISyntax>
              <CommunicationAddress Type="SMTP">ediel@7Hkraft.se</CommunicationAddress>
              <InterchangePartyId IdCodeQualifier="ZZ">60900</InterchangePartyId>
              <PartyId IdCodeQualifier="160" IdCodeResponsible="SVK">60900</PartyId>
            </EDIFACTDetails>
            <EDIFACTDetails Type="UTILTS">
              <EDICharset>UNOC</EDICharset>
              <EDISyntax>3</EDISyntax>
              <CommunicationAddress Type="SMTP">ediel@7Hkraft.se</CommunicationAddress>
              <InterchangePartyId IdCodeQualifier="ZZ">60900</InterchangePartyId>
              <PartyId IdCodeQualifier="SVK" IdCodeResponsible="260">60900</PartyId>
            </EDIFACTDetails>
          </EDIFACTAddressing>
          <NBSAddressing>
            <NBSDetails Type="NBS">
              <EnergyPartyId IdentifierType="EdielId">60900</EnergyPartyId>
            </NBSDetails>
          </NBSAddressing>
        </EdielAddressing>
      </Company>
    </Market>
  </CompanyListMessage>
</ExportPartyAddressingResponse>
```

I have tried the following SQL statement, just to first get info from header tag...

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT N'http://www.ediel.no/Export')
    SELECT
        t.file_name, t.file_created_time,
        h.value(N'(GeneratedAt/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') h1,
        h.value(N'@GeneratedAt', 'varchar(50)') h2
    FROM
        load.ediel_actors t
    OUTER APPLY
        t.xml_data.nodes('/ExportPartyAddressingResponse/CompanyListMessage') AS header(h)
```

I can't figure out why my SQL isn't working. Is it the namespace definition or is it the code for retrieving values?

I am using SQL Server 2019.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

**(1)**: your XPath expression is wrong - you must also include the `/Header` part to get the `<Header>` XML element selected

**(2)**: your `h1` expression is wrong - since you're trying to get the value of an **attribute** on the XML element, you need to use the expression in your second line.

So try this:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT N'http://www.ediel.no/Export')
    SELECT
        t.Col1,
        h.value(N'@GeneratedAt', 'varchar(50)') HeaderGeneratedAt,
        h.value(N'@SenderApplication', 'varchar(50)') SenderApplication
    FROM
        @datatbl t
    OUTER APPLY
        t.xmldata.nodes('/ExportPartyAddressingResponse/CompanyListMessage/Header') AS header(h)
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked on header. Now i have issue that i don't know how to filer the XML. In the XML in node "Market" (same level as "Header") you can see it says Code="EL" (it means electricity) and it seems to be because file has info for both electricity market actors and gas(as in for the stove/oven) actors and it is showing it as 2 concurrent nodes with same "Market" name but the first one has "EL" and second one has "Gas". So i guess i need some method to filter XML on node Market code="EL".

Comment: Nevermind it was more SQL like to filter nodes. It was enough to do

`WHERE m.value(N'@Code', 'varchar(50)') = 'EL'`

Comment: How would you retreive the values in node 
/ExportPartyAddressingResponse/CompanyListMessage/Market/Company/Identifiers ?

I am only able to retreive the values using indexed position like so..:

value(N'(Identifiers/Key/text())[1]', 'varchar(80)')

But what then ends up happening is that if second attribute in the node isn't always "OrgNo" i would end up with wrong data in column.

I need to find some way of mapping the attributes position but i am stuck.

Comment: I got it working! I found hint in other thread. In order to retreive values based on element name i used...
`c.value(N'(Identifiers/Key[@Type = "EdielId"]/text())[1]', 'varchar(80)')`
It is the @Type = "" which makes it work.